# No me toma el responsive para celular

Tags: css, responsive, mediaqueries

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se porque no me toma el responsive del celular ya intente de todo. Aca dejo el link`introducir el código aquí`
https://candela24.github.io/lalicv/.
`introducir el código aquí`



LaliCV

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes dos imágenes iguales de tu código? Es confuso e inexacto. ¿Podrías sencillamente copiar el código CSS? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese media querie no te funcionará principalmente por que no tienes ninguna clase que se llame 'pasos' en esa url.

Comment: perdon me confundi de foto esa no es la del link, ahora la cambio pero hay otro problema?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta línea:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
```

por esta otra y prueba de nuevo:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
```

Fuente: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Ya nos contarás si te ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes un media querie dentro de otro media querie.

```
@media(min-width:600px) and (max-width:990px){
    ...

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        ...
    }
}
```

El segundo media querie nunca aplicará ya que en pantallas de menos de 600px todo lo que está dentro de el primer media querie no aplica...

La solución será sacar el media querie (max-width: 600px) fuera del primero.

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que mantengas un orden de identación en el código ya que te ayudará a encontrar estos errores y será mas fácil de leer.